# Isn't [scope] out of scope?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope) doesn't have a clear scope! It doesn't have a tag wiki either and the tag info reads "Scope is an enclosing context where values and expressions are associated. Use this tag for questions about different types of scope as well for questions where scope may be unclear." Pretty vague!

There are about 9792 questions and the tag doesn't add any meaningful information to the 100 odd questions that I checked out. Shouldn't it be burninated?